# Get ahead - get a hat

Tags: discussion

Each year Stack Exchange has a few weeks of awarding hats based on tasks or accomplishments on the site. People can then display their favorite hats on their profile and avatar. It's called Winter Bash, and if you haven't already seen it in previous years on other Stack Exchange sites, [here's some info on last year's one](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/12/winter-bash-2014/).

This year the hats will be available from 14th December to 3rd January. Since most Stack Exchange sites enjoy the hats (quite a lot...), this year it is automatic for all sites unless we choose to opt out. Individuals can also opt out with the "I hate hats" button that will appear at the time.

I'm looking forward to the hats but since this is our first year I wanted to give the opportunity for anyone to voice any concerns or objections. If there are none, we'll automatically have hats very soon...

***If we do find a reason to opt out as a site, we need to make a final decision by Wednesday 9th December 2015.***

Comment: I see no reason to opt out.